# No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, initwithstyle

I instantiate a UITableView in a UIViewController when the view is loaded as :

```
table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y + hauteurFavorisCell, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-hauteurFavorisCell-hauteurNavigationBar)];

[table registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"DetailsFavoris"];
table.delegate = self;
table.dataSource = self;
table.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview:table];
```

The problem is that I want the cell to have style : UITableViewCellStyleValue1. Because the cells are create with the method initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault. I can't use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier. My code is thus :

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DetailsFavoris";

```
UITableViewCell *cell ;//= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

...

return cell;
```

But I would like to reuse the cells to be more efficient. I wrote down :

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    // ignore the style argument, use our own to override
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // If you need any further customization
    }
    return self;
}
```

But I got an error : No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:.

What am I doing wrong? I checked on other answers but I found nothing.

Comment: Where are you implementing your `initWithStyle:…`?  The error suggests that you are doing it inside a subclass of UIViewController instead of a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: Indeed, I wrote it on my subclass of UIVIewController. When I instantiate my UItableView 'table' in the ViewDidLoad, it creates cells with default style automatically. Where am I supposed to write the initWithStyle method then?

Answer (score 1):

Move this code

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    // ignore the style argument, use our own to override
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // If you need any further customization
    }
    return self;
}
```

To your `UITableViewCell` subclass. Because this method related to `UITableViewCell` class, not to `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thanks! I created a UITableViewCell subclass for my cell and it works now.

Comment: @yaniki so, if problem solved - you can accept my the answer ;)